# How to make a URL redirect in php

Tags: php, wordpress

We have a Yahoo Hosting account and had a old website that had .html files. Our new site is running WordPress but due to Yahoo hosting rules they don't install WordPress in the root folder and make you install it in sub folder /blog.

They don't give you access to .htaccess or anything so I could not use that. What the put in the root dir is a index.php file below is what's in it.

I wan't to know is there a way I could add to it an example of what I'm trying to do is below.

Example
Old URL: http://example.net/TuitionFees.html
New URL  http://example.net/blog/tuition/

This is what Yahoo has in the main dir. index.php

```
<?php
/* Short and sweet */
define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);
define('WP_IN_ROOTDIR', true);
require('.//blog/wp-blog-header.php');
?>
```

Comment: This question has already been already answered thoroughly [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-do-i-make-a-redirect-in-php]).

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the `wp_redirect()` function that wordpress provides.

Example:

```
wp_redirect( $url );
exit;
```

See more here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect/